# Получение ID рубрики WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста. Есть файл category.php , там будет код вывода записей определенных рубрик, то есть 1 файл на все рубрики (ну думаю это понятно)), так вот.. Как получить ID рубрики именно в этом файле? По get_cat_ID не вариант, т.к. придется для каждой рубрики вводить название самостоятельно, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID текущей категории содержится в глобальной переменной `$cat`.

```
global $cat;

echo $cat;
```